# Dificuldades com método binarySearch da Classe Arrays

Tags: java, array

Criei dois arrays um de inteiros e outro de Strings(objetos), mas quando usei o método binarySearch pra saber a posição dos elementos, o retorno das posições do array de Strings saiu diferente, por que isso aconteceu?

mostrando código e e retorno.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ArraySimples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] paises ={"Brasil", "Russia", "India", "China", "Argentina","Paraguai"};
        int [] numeros = {5,7,9,11,13};
        int posicao0 =Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Brasil");
        int posicao1 =Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Russia");
        int posicao2 =Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "India");
        int posicao3 =Arrays.binarySearch(paises, " China");
        int posicao4 =Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Argentina");
        int posicao5 =Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Paraguai");

        System.out.println("Brasil: " + posicao0);
        System.out.println("Russia: " + posicao1);
        System.out.println("India: " + posicao2);
        System.out.println("China: " + posicao3);
        System.out.println("Argentina:" + posicao4);
        System.out.println("Paraguai" + posicao5);

        int posicao00 =Arrays.binarySearch(numeros, 5);
        int posicao11 =Arrays.binarySearch(numeros, 7);
        int posicao22 =Arrays.binarySearch(numeros, 9);
        int posicao33 =Arrays.binarySearch(numeros, 11);
        int posicao44 =Arrays.binarySearch(numeros, 13);
        System.out.println("5: " + posicao00);
        System.out.println("7: " + posicao11);
        System.out.println("9: " + posicao22);
        System.out.println("11: " + posicao33);
        System.out.println("13: " +posicao44);
    }
}
```

[image: Esse foi o resulta, porque apareceram posições negativas?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para usar `binarySearch`, antes você precisa ter um Array ordenado.

Se fizer isso, já muda o resultado (mas leia até o final):

```
java.util.Arrays.sort();
```

Veja este trecho da [documentação do Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object)):

> The array must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(Object[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Traduzindo:

> O array precisa estar organizado em ordem crescente de acordo com a ordem natural dos seus elementos (como pelo método sort(Object[]) antes de fazer esta chamada. Se não estiver organizado, os resultados são indefinidos.

Perceba que como os números do seu teste **já estavam ordenados** no source, o resultado foi esperado. Os países, por sua vez, não estão em ordem natural. Se estivessem em ordem também, provavelmente não perceberiamos um potencial problema.

A solução, aplicada ao seu código, é simples... mas leia atentamente o que vem depois.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArraySimples {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String [] paises ={"Brasil", "Russia", "India", "China", "Argentina", "Paraguai"};

      Arrays.sort(paises);

      int posicao0 = Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Brasil");
      int posicao1 = Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Russia");
      int posicao2 = Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "India");
      int posicao3 = Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "China");
      int posicao4 = Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Argentina");
      int posicao5 = Arrays.binarySearch(paises, "Paraguai");

      System.out.println("Brasil: " + posicao0);
      System.out.println("Russia: " + posicao1);
      System.out.println("India: " + posicao2);
      System.out.println("China: " + posicao3);
      System.out.println("Argentina: " + posicao4);
      System.out.println("Paraguai: " + posicao5);
   }
}
```

### Funcionar é diferente de estar certo :D

Fazer busca binária só interessa quando são várias. Muito mais buscas e em momentos diferentes do que o que está na pergunta, como uma lista inteira de países que vai ser consultada inúmeras vezes no código.

Senão, é muito melhor fazer um loop `for`.

Para você entender melhor, vamos usar um exemplo mais prático:

Você tem 600 livros, misturados, e quer só um, "O Processo" de Kafka.

O `sort` + `binarySearch` é você primeiro organizar TODOS 600 em ordem alfabética... e só depois que terminar de ordenar, começa a procurar. Pega o do meio, vê se é o que quer, se não for divide a pilha em dois, procura de um dos lados, e assim vai, até chegar no desejado (sendo que ao ordenar o livro já passou várias vezes na sua mão e vc nao pegou). Percebe que essa alternativa não é muito inteligente?

Muito melhor é simplesmente olhar um por um na sequência, e quando achar o que quer, pega e sai. Fim da história. Ou seja, no caso de uma ou duas buscas só, a saída mesmo é esquecer esse negócio de busca binária e usar um simples loop.

Comment: Obrigado Bacco, ajudou bastante :)