# Valor incorreto no vetor quando faço busca binária

Tags: java, array, java-8, busca-binária

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * @author Vinicius
 *
 */
public class Vetor04 {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vet[] = {3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 5};
        int s = Arrays.binarySearch(vet, 3);
        System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

Estou tentando fazer a o índice 3 do vetor `vet` aparecer mas ao invés de imprimir 1 imprime -5, qual o motivo disso acontecer?

Comment: Pesquisa binária tem o principio da ordenação ... acho que esse método segue isso.

Comment: Todo conhecimento é válido, e você pode observar que as soluções podem caber dentro de um problema. Todas as experiências são válidas e respondi de acordo com a pergunta. Se a sua dúvida era sobre aquele método foi respondido e explicado de acordo com o seu questionamento e os motivos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como eu relatei no comentário, a pesquisa binária tem o principio da ordenação crescente, e o seu `array` não está ordenado dessa forma do menor para o maior valor. Faça a ordenação com `Arrays.sort` que o local do valor é retornado, ***exemplo***:

```
int vet[] = {3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 5};
Arrays.sort(vet); // ordenação
int s = Arrays.binarySearch(vet, 3);
System.out.println(s);
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://ideone.com/AN22PZ)

Porque os números estranhos, *segundo o livro da Kathy Sierra página 322*, 
***As buscas bem-sucedidas retornam o índice do elemento sendo procurado*** e ***Buscas mal-sucedidas retornam um índice int que representa o ponto de inserção***.

Eu exemplifiquei sobre o código da pergunta, não podemos imaginar outra forma se na pergunta está descrito assim, claro (programação é sem limites) que pode ser feito de outra forma. As razões muitas vezes que levaram a esse questionamento é a explicação do texto anterior, ou seja, a falta de conhecimento sobre o que está fazendo.

Vale lembrar que aqui no site tem uma resposta praticamente igual [Dificuldades com método binarySearch da Classe Arrays](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12983/dificuldades-com-m%C3%A9todo-binarysearch-da-classe-arrays) e foi citado a mesma solução.

Claro que poderia ter utilizado outros formas de pesquisas, como por exemplo [Linear](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_linear), mas, eu vou sempre pela pergunta.

Answer (score 8):

Embora você queira usar o método `Arrays.binarySearch()` para achar um valor em um *array* não classificado (o termo correto, porque ordenado o *array* está, ele tem uma ordem, a ordem de entrada de dados) e este método não deve ser aplicado. Ele foi criado para lidar quando você tem dados já classificados.

A solução de classificar o *array* para depois fazer a busca binária funciona, mas não está certo:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Só vale a pena usar uma busca binária com uma coleção de dados que é garantidamente classificada já que o esforço de classificação é, no mínimo (e seria em uma condição ideal que na prática não acontece) igual a fazer uma busca linear, geralmente é bem maior. E na prática o algoritmo de classificação é menos eficiente até mesmo no detalhe que a busca linear na maioria das situações porque ela é ruim de localidade de referência. Pra ser mais preciso a busca linear chegar ser melhor até mesmo em *arrays* pequenos que já estão classificados.

Então se quer aprender aplicar o algoritmo de maneira correta não deve aplicar neste caso. Está aprendendo usar o mecanismo, mas também está aprendendo usá-lo da maneira incorreta e pode te perseguir pra sempre. E não estamos falando de pequena diferença quando os volumes são maiores, você poderá criar situações bem trágicas se continuar fazendo assim porque aprendeu que resolve no Stack Overflow.

Fazendo a busca linear produz o mesmo resultado de forma muito mais eficiente. Ainda que não precise dessa eficiência em um exercício o objetivo nem é este, é ensinar certo para aplicar bem nas próximas vezes:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int vet[] = { 3, 7, 6, 1, 9, 4, 5 };
        for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) if (vet[i] == 3) {System.out.println(i); break; }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7iBZ9D). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/LinearSearchjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/LinearSearch.java).

Tem várias outras formas de fazer isto.

E note que ele retorna a posição real, você pode querer isto ou não. A função pronto retorna a posição de inserção.

O pior caso deste algoritmo é O(N), mas pode ser O(1) no melhor caso. O melhor caso da busca binária que precisa classificar o dado é O(N)+O(1), mas na prática isto não acontece e a maioria dos casos será O(NlogN)+O(1) podendo até mesmo ser O(N2)+O(1). Em grandes volumes pode sair de segundos para horas.

Sem falar que assim não corre o risco do *array* não estar classificado e dar errado, como aconteceu. E a única forma de garantir em um código maior é:

- classificar todas as vezes que for fazer a busca binária (muito ineficiente)
- usar uma estrutura que você garante que foi classificada de início e não é mais mudada
- usar uma estrutura que vai se classificando automaticamente toda vez que é mudada.

Pode não ser o que o AP quer, mas é importante para outras pessoas saberem o modo correto de fazer este tipo de coisa e não aprender errado. Note que isto está errado até mesmo neste caso proposto na pergunta, mesmo que funcione, a não ser que na pergunta estivesse escrito, a performance não importa e digitar menos caracteres importa.

Leia os comentários abaixo tem informações extras importantes.

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o porque de estar errado o uso do  'Arrays.binarySearch()' mas obrigado por ter ajudado me mostrando uma forma alternativa de fazer.

Comment: Justamente que pelo que eu falei, não é eficiente. Você quer ir de SP ao Rio, mas não tem um carro, o que é melhor, pegar um ônibus ou comprar um carro só para isto? Ou olhando de outra forma, o que é melhor, ir a pé até lá ou fabricar um carro para poder ir? Muitos devem ter a impressão que um método simples de uma linha é algo bom, mas o que ocorre dentro dele é uma enormidade de processamento. Eu quis fazer em uma linha justamente porque as pessoas olham mais que uma e acham que é pior.

Comment: @SDWQ12 simplificando: `Arrays.binarySearch()` é para ser usado quando o vetor já vai estar naturalmente ordenado pelo seu código. Se não está, é melhor usar outras soluções, e não `binarySearch`. A solução mais óbvia é o loop for (que é o que está aqui na resposta correta). Talvez a linguagem até já tenha um método de busca linear, que tende a ser melhor que a binária.

Comment: @SDWQ12 é importante você entender o motivo, para tomar decisões corretas no futuro. Quando você recorre a um `sort` só para logo em seguida fazer `search`, demonstra desconhecimento de algoritmos e outras coisas fundamentais, pois só o sort sozinho já consome muito mais recursos do que um for (ele vai fazer geralmente mais de um for internamente e repassar pelos elementos mais de uma vez, pois trabalhará sobre todos e não somente no que você precisa). Recomendo estudara algoritmos de ordenação, e comparar as soluções.

Comment: @Bacco não tem :D Até tem aquela coisa de Streams, mas dá até mais trabalho :D Grande falha. Qualquer linguagem deveria ter por padrão um `indexOf()` em (quase) todas coleções de dados.

Comment: @SDWQ12 exemplo "real". Você tem 600 livros, misturados, e  quer "O Processo" de Kafka. O `for` é você olhando um por um na sequência, e quando achar, pega e sai. Fim da história. O `sort` + `binarySearch` é você primeiro organizar TODOS 600 em ordem alfabética... e só depois que terminar de ordenar, começa a procurar. Pega o do meio, vê se é o que quer, se não for divide a pilha em dois, procura de um dos lados, e assim vai, até chegar no desejado (sendo que ao ordenar o livro já passou várias vezes na sua mão e vc nao pegou). Percebe que essa segunda alternativa não é muito inteligente?

Comment: O que muitas vezes acontece é o programador não lembrar que quando ele faz um `metodoDaLinguagem()` a coisa não acontece magicamente. Isso está chamando um código que faz toda uma série de operações. É uma função cheia de código. Simplesmente ocorre que outro programador escreveu a função pra você e incluiu na linguagem, mas ela existe e a máquina vai ter que executar todos aqueles passos (independente do código ter vindo pronto e você não ter sido apresentado ao fonte dele, ou de um que você mesmo escreveu).

Comment: Eu acredito que nós somos desenvolvedores e que precisamos com tudo aprender sempre, mas, o mais legal desse pt.stackoverflow é saber que existe outra resposta como o mesmo problema citados na sua resposta, porque, na minha visão só quis expor porque de não dar certo e claro que eu sei e não usaria isso para fazer essa busca. Enfim não vi ninguém ir nessa resposta e fazer esse estardalhaço, porque, até parece duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12983/dificuldades-com-m%C3%A9todo-binarysearch-da-classe-arrays

Comment: @VirgilioNovic bem observado, vou complementar lá.

Comment: A única pessoa fazendo estardalhaço é você. A única pessoa que ficou desesperada, saiu criando comentários quem nem louco, editando pra colocar informação para dizer que sua resposta é maravilhosa, que saiu procurando no site alguma coisa parecida é você e colocar na sua resposta como se fosse um troféu, a única pessoa que está com uma preocupação enorme com isso é você. Eu só dei uma resposta que ajuda as pessoas se tornarem desenvolvedores e evitar a síndrome do codificador que faz funcionar e entende errado. Eu acho que é bom para a comunidade

Comment: Poderia usar esse esforço todo para achar duplicatas antes de responder. Mas note que tem uma diferença lá, várias buscas foram feitas, não apenas uma, aí já pode compensar fazer a classificação, depende de alguns fatores, no caso ali provavelmente compensaria.

Comment: @Maniero cara pode dizer o que você bem entender, não faz diferença as suas atitudes comigo e falar isso como forma de estar certo e sempre certo é o seu estilo. Quando um moderador pede para responder a pergunta que faz só se tiver certeza do que vai responder pra mim é uma exclusão de pessoas. Bom obrigado.

Comment: Se não fizesse diferença você não se importaria tanto quanto se importa. Demonstre não fazer diferença ignorando. Quando resolver ter esse esforço todo está claramente mostrando que faz um diferença enorme na sua vida.

Comment: Só respondi para você não falar sozinho @Maniero porque sempre tem razão.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Complementei, explicando a diferença de uma busca avulsa, e de fazer um sort pra várias (que é o caso daquela). Se tiver mais sugestões, avise aqui ou lá que eu complemento se entender que está correto. Toda melhoria é bem vinda.

Comment: @Bacco vote como duplicata então?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic como aquela é minha eu sou suspeito pra falar... Me deu a impressão que aquela tem uma pergunta mais clara no sentido do problema, mas como a resposta é minha, deixo pra comunidade decidir.

Comment: @Bacco você viu que o array não estava ordernado e citou a mesma coisa do que eu fiz, porque a minha preocupação é responder a pergunta em nenhum momento ele disse que poderia propor uma melhor forma de fazer isso, então a sua resposta está certo no contexto igual eu respondi. A sua resposta e a minha são iguais e a do Maniero vejo como complemento de não fazer agora eu acho complicado o que foi feito já visto que a sua resposta é a mesma coisa.